# Divs height is determined by text height within and I don't want this

Tags: html, css

I have the following div in an angular view, this is all that is in the view as of now

```
<div class="home-container" ng-controller="ctrlHome" >
 HELLO
</div>
```

I want to set it's background image to take up the rest of the page or the same amount as the body

here is the css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Hero", Times, serif !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.home-container {
    background: url('../images/94H.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

All I am getting it the image the height of the text HELLO which is 20px
This is probably something easy I am screwing up but it's frustrating non the less
Thanks in advance

[image: image of div being height of text]

Comment: try adding `html` to body rule ...`html, body {...`

Answer (score 0):

Use `height: 100%` instead of min-height. Also add `html` to the CSS rule since body needs a parent element to calculate `height: 100%`

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Hero", Times, serif !important;
  height: 100%; /* Changed */
}
.home-container {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/600x1200') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-container" ng-controller="ctrlHome">
  HELLO
</div>
```

Comment: yes but it being a view it may effect it, I'll show you want I'm getting, I'll add an image